# Connection reset for https connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

The code

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;    

public static HttpsURLConnection httpsCon(String httpsURL, String query){
            try{
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                      new X509TrustManager() {
                          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                              return null;
                          }
                          public void checkClientTrusted(
                              java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                          }
                          public void checkServerTrusted(
                              java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                          }
                      }
                  };
                  // Install the all-trusting trust manager   
                  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");   
                  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());   
                  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());   
                  // Create all-trusting host name verifier   
                  HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {   
                      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {   
                          return true;   
                      }   
                  }; 
                  // Install the all-trusting host verifier   
                  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid); 
                   URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
                  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
                  con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                  con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
                  con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                  con.setDoOutput(true); 
                  con.setDoInput(true); 
                  return con;
            }catch(Exception ce){
                log.info("IndoUtil.httpscon()"+IndoUtil.getFullLog(ce));
            }
                return null;
        }
```

When I am passing a https url to that method I am getting the below exception, I am unable to find the problem, Some one please point out

The actual line which cause exception is **con.getOutputStream()**

```
HttpsURLConnection con = IndoUtil.httpsCon(httpsURL, query);    
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
```

> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   com.ibm.indo.serviceImpl.GenericServiceImpl.checkDompetkuReg(GenericServiceImpl.java:2042)
>     at
>   com.ibm.indo.controller.IndoServiceController.customerProfile(IndoServiceController.java:140)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>     at com.ibm.indo.util.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Sometimes it happens when server does not trust client, or client starts to renegotiate to a different TLS version, etc. Enable SSL debug of JVM, e.g: add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` and post the output into your question.

Comment: This is a remote server I have very limited access. thanks

Comment: I got to know. The same code is running from a test server. What could be missing in jboss??

Comment: Anyone, Is it anything to do with static? I doubt cause in Test the traffic is less where as in PROD is much